# Bitmap inPurgable behavior in android

Tags: android, bitmap

can any one explain how the `inPurgable` option works when it set to true ? 
from the  [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory)

> If this is set to true, then the resulting bitmap will allocate its
>   pixels  such that they can be purged if the system needs to reclaim
>   memory. In that  instance, when the pixels need to be accessed again
>   (e.g. the bitmap is  drawn, getPixels() is called), they will be
>   automatically re-decoded. For  the re-decode to happen, the bitmap
>   must have access to the encoded data,  either by sharing a reference
>   to the input or by making a copy of it.

My interpretation of this is it will either keep a reference to the filename 
the bitmap pixels were loaded from or it will make a copy of the pixels 
somewhere. For the former, can I expect drawBitmap to then perform a 
potentially slow IO operation in my onDraw method if the bitmap was purged? 
For the latter, how is the copy made and what is the memory usage impact of 
this?